# Where to find really good articles on stocks and general trading information?

Tags: investing, stocks, options, trading

Apart from this website, are there any other websites out there that are focused on trading and investing?.

I am looking for a website where I can find articles etc on trading and investment - say stocks, options or futures. Anything from beginner to advanced material will be useful.

Can anyone recommend such a site/sites?

Comment: Sarcasm: Storybook.  All stock derivatives tools value are utterly useless without a story to fill up.

Answer (score 3):

[The Motley Fool](http://www.fool.com) is a great site for education and have an excellent forum for discussion of stocks and investing.

Answer (score 1):

**[Seeking Alpha](http://seekingalpha.com/)** has complete articles for a variety of levels, from beginner to advanced. The quality is uneven, but some content is very good. By reading the site's  articles for awhile, you'll get a good sense of which authors are good, and who is just okay.

Comment: Seeking Alpha has a lot of useful  general information but you should take many of the opinions there with a grain of salt. Anyone can write and submit an article for publication there (and payment for it) and many of the authors have no clue. Their primary agenda is to drive readers toward $ubscription$. In and of itself, a profit motive isn't a  problem but SA will defend their authors, even when  abjectly wrong,  to the point of censuring readers who correct author errors. I’ve seen many informed contributors leave the site in frustration.

Comment: For the same "alpha", broker A says sell, broker B says buy, while broker C says hold.  In the end, the retail investor is the sucker.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Investopedia is the most comprehensive source of investment information with which you can build a broad base of basic financial literacy.  Beyond that, you're going to have to delve into more detailed books.